# Runtime.exec fails without any exception/warning/error code

Tags: java, runtime, exec

This is really weird and eating away my brains. I am using Runtime.exec to start another jvm and it quietly exits even without starting.

```
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java classname", null, new File(workdir));
```

The process exits immediately. I briefly see the process in taskmanager and it goes off. I even tried to capture the output.

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String errString = "Error Details:\n";
        String line;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            errString = errString.concat(line).concat("\n");
```

The line is null at the first readline call. I know i could use ProcessBuilder but i am on java 1.4 and i cannot go for 1.5. Please help.

Thanks, Bikash

Comment: try reading the error stream to see what happened.

Comment: The first argument to `exec()` is the process executable, i.e. `java` or `java.exe`, not the name of the Java class whose `main()` is to be executed.

Comment: Please don't ever change your question in a fundamental way. Just create a new question. You may link to the old one, if appropriate. There are many reasons not to do so: The headline, which is useful for people with the same problem (which one?) is confusing; two threads intermixed are confusing; you can only accept one message; upvoting does not allow to distinguish for which question the upvote counts; tags may only fit to one question; and so on. I rolled the question back to it's old state. Please don't restore. But you may use the edit facility to copy your 2nd text for creating anewone.

Comment: Hello user unknown,

At least i had posted a solution which you deleted. Nevermind, i think solutions are not entertained if posted by the questioner himself or herself. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the commands in a command line array:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"java", "classname"}, null, new File(workdir));
```

Answer (score 1):

I always point to [this site](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) when people are having problems with Runtime.exec()